# Block NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

After finally [recovering](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17522) from the [System.Net.Http](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23306) [package](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773) [hell](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781) we would like to block the package entirely.

I'm looking for a way to block the package from ever installing, so not blocking or locking a version but the entire package (due to a dependency or developer error). The block should be in the solution folder of the application so that every developer will have the block once updating from SVN.

I've looked at the NuGet.config and .nuspec documentation but was unable to find such a feature. My Google-fu also didn't yield any results. So I was wondering if there was anybody here that knows if and how it can be done.

I've opened up a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7378)

Comment: Since a lot of packages depend on it, do you want to skip .NET Standard and .NET Core entirely?

Comment: Feels a little overreacting to me personally.

Comment: Yes, we only develop on .NET Framework so there is no need to mix. Secondly we would like to avoid errors when deploying to production as compilation on the local machine works fine. And thirdly binding redirects are the root of most evil and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: You can't block packages. Nuget doesn't include this feature.

Comment: @Patrick this is not overreacting, this mess has hit me hard as well. There are specific package versions who silently pull in .NET Standard on .NET Framework 4.6-4.7, and that cause conflicting or erroneous binding redirects in the applications they're installed in.

Comment: @CodeCaster Okay, thanks for the insight. Is blocking the package the 'solution' in your opinion?

Comment: @Patrick it would be a very nice option if NuGet would have a way to blacklist certain packages versions or dependencies, but I'm quite sure that's not possible, at least not without running your own NuGet (proxy) server.

Comment: MS really have b**ls up this haven't they. .Net (framework/core/standard) really is a total mess at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you can lock _dependencies_ to a specific version, but not prevent installing certain versions in a project.

Comment: You could secure the nuget cache folder against writing that specific folder :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman i don't think that options scales to multiple dev machines :(

Comment: That wasn't one of your requirements. @Sc0tTy

Comment: Added @PatrickHofman

Comment: if you are using Git you can create git pre-commit hook, that checks if any of packages.config contanins System.Net.Http and don't allow those commits

Answer (score 3):

I can maybe offer a workaround. We wanted a similar thing (prevent referencing  WinForms dependencies) and added a unit test that checks whether specific assemblies are referenced:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> BlockedAssemblies = new List<string>
{   
    "System.Net.Http"
};

[Test]
public void SpecificAssembliesAreNotReferenced()
{
    var asm = Assembly.Load("Your.Assembly.File");

    var refs = asm.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach(var a in refs)
    {
        Assert.False(BlockedAssemblies.Contains (a.Name), $"{a.Name} must not be referenced.");
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, and doesn't actually block the package from being downloaded, but it prevents accidental referencing and usage of an assembly.